# Print keyword displays blank when response includes long encoded chars

Tags: karate

I am testing an endpoint that takes a json body as request and return a json object with one field with encoded value for a pdf generation. I get 201 status code, but I could not get to print the response. It looks blank in console.

Sample Request Paylaod might be;

```
{'name': 'firstName',
 'lname': lastname }
```

and response looks like below;

```
{ 'getPDF': 'JBKJGHUKSxjsnckdskcnejcnd/vdsv+VFDVfsd..........'}
```

And I just print the response as below;

```
* status 201
* print response
```

but it does not print anything. Is there a way to print the encoded value in the response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that the response is actually empty. Anyway if it is bytes, you can try convert to a string:

```
* string response = responseBytes
```

If that doesn't work - who knows, Karate may have a bug :) So please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi, response is not empty. it is a huge encoded string returned as response but no luck printing it. I will try to submit an issue when possible. Thanks.